# How can I bind the python built in functions?

Tags: python, function, built-in

I don't even know if this is possible.

I want to do something like:

```
>>> foo = float
>>> x = foo('2')
>>> x
2
```

But when I try it I get a type object in foo:

```
>>> foo = float
>>> foo
<type 'int'>
```

I want to save a structure like object that holds the correct function to call when converting values to be read from a file.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That's very strange. I just typed that and got the expected result. (Note that in your first example, `x` should be `2.0`, not `2`.)

Comment: Almost certainly this is because float has been rebound to int.

Comment: @Taymon thank you, I don't know what I was doing, you are totally right.

Comment: @DSM yes, rebound to an int object (not int type).

Comment: @SenthilKumaran: no, to the int type.  If float had been rebound to some int object, then x = foo('2') would have raised `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible; the identifiers for builtins are no different from any other identifiers, and there's no reason you can't bind your own identifiers to the same objects.

If you're not getting the expected results, check and make sure you haven't accidentally rebound the identifiers to other values.

Answer (score -1):

You can just bind them. But that is not an advisable thing to do because your overriding the default behavior with something else and functions which you relying on the default behavior would unexpectedly break. **So do not do that!**

```
>>> foo = float
>>> bar = int
>>> foo('2')
2.0
>>> bar('2')
2
>>> type(foo)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(bar)
<type 'type'>
>>>
```

Comment: You should be a little more clear about what is not advisable...  doing `foo=int` is fine (I think ... I'm sure this is done in `optparse,argparse,ConfigParser` ...) where the "type" is passed as an argument to various functions.  However, doing `int=float` is definitely a bad idea.

Comment: -1 Relying on the default behaviour of `float`? The OP is not changing its behaviour. And `foo` doesn't have a default behaviour ...

Comment: John Machin - Yeah, I see that. Sorry, I got confused!